carrying participle?
There's a subject that's been on my mind a lot lately. Are the participles in these sentences in adverb manner? What difference does it make if we put a comma before participles?
They sat at the back of the church praying quietly.
Emily earned enough money to buy a car working hard.
However, sea trade became more widespread when large sailing boats travelled between ports, carrying spices, perfumes and objects made by hand.
I cut the paper using a ruler

For what it’s worth, your Emily example sounds awkward. It would be much better if you either (1) moved to buy a car to the end of the sentence and set off working hard with commas or (2) moved working hard, with a comma, to the start of the sentence.
